# how can I automatically copy data from multiple columns on a tab and paste it on a single column on another tab in the same workbook?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to find a formula that I can copy the data from columns H to Q on "Master" sheet

[image]

and paste it into column D on another tab ("Sheet1") in the same workbook

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `TOCOL()` function. Put below formula to Sheet1 `D2` cell.

```
=TOCOL(Sheet2!H2:Q50000,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately on my office 365 the TOCOL function does not show-up on the formula bar.

Comment: @emald Then try `FILTERXML()` like `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,H2:Q200)&"</s></t>","//s")`.

Comment: Thanks again! It almost works, but my data on the first tab goes over 1300 rows. When I change the formula to H2:Q2000 or anything over 200 I get an "#CALC!" on the cells

Comment: As per [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c), `TEXTJOIN()` has character limitation.

Comment: Is there any other way that I can get the results that I am looking for? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VSTACK to pull all the columns from one sheet into a single column in another sheet.  If you don't want blanks you can combine VSTACK and FILTER. I made a quick set of sample data to mimic what you posted, below.  Then used the VSTACK and FILTER functions to pull it into one column. Modify as needed to pull into new spreadsheet.
[image]